# Cells show the value member (ID) instead Display member

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, .net-3.5

I'm currently working with C# and I have the following code to set a ComboBox column inside a DGV:

```
// Add the values of the combo box
dgvcbGeneric.DataSource = dtDataSource;
dgvcbGeneric.ValueMember = "ID";
dgvcbGeneric.DisplayMember = "Value";
dgvcbGeneric.DataPropertyName = strColumn;
dgvcbGeneric.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;

dgvcbGeneric.DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly = true;
// vGenericCMB.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic

dgvcbGeneric.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = columns[strActualColumn].nullFormat;

// Add the new ComboBoxColumn of the DGV
dgvLink.Columns.Add(dgvcbGeneric);
```

[image]

All works fine, but the DGV only show the member value when the cell has the focus:

[image]

Someone can explain me why this issue is happening?

Comment: I replaced `strColumn` with `"Day"` and `columns[strActualColumn].nullFormat` with `null` and it works fine for me.  The focused cell displays a `ComboBox` and once a value is selected and the cell loses focus, it still displays the `Value` instead of the `ID`.  I don't know if the `NullValue` could have that effect, but I can't tell because I don't know what values you have in that variable.

Comment: The value has a null value. The problem is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error by myself. Basically in the DataSource of the DGV the column "Day" was of type "Byte" (tinyint in SQL).
When the code try to create the DataTable to fill up the DGV ComboBox Column; the ID type is "Integer".

The solution was check the DataType of the ID vs the column source. If are differents; throw an exception to check previously.

Comment: I had the same problem with "long" and "int" types. Problem solved after changing the types in the DB.