# DatagridviewComboBoxCell of datagridview not working as expected

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview where one of the cell has a type as `DatagridviewComboBoxCell`. For this cell I associated datasource to it and mentioned `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Now on loading the grid, I am able to see the cell with a dropdown and all the desired items. But when I select a particular item and move to some other cell then this `ComboBoxcell` shows `ValueMember` rather than `DisplayMember`.

E.g. Combobox has months listed in it like `January, February...December`. So here the DisplayMember is `January,February...December` and the `ValueMember` is respective month number like `1,2,3...12`. So when I select say `January` and move to any other cell, the `ComboBoxCell` shows month number i.e. `1`  here in case of `January`.

I want the cell to show `January` or `DisplayMember` in generic term and NOT a `ValueMember`.

Please let me know how can I achieve this. Please note that I don't want to use entire column as `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Here is the code:

```
Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DateName(M,'1900-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, X.iMonth) + '-01') sMonth, X.iMonth " & _
                                         " FROM (SELECT TOP 12 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) iMonth from sys.objects) X", Conn)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim ComboCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

            DataGridView1("sNotes", dr.Index) = ComboCell
            ComboCell.DataSource = dt
            ComboCell.DisplayMember = "sMonth"
            ComboCell.ValueMember = "iMonth"
        Next
```

[image]

Comment: Please share with us your relevant piece/s of code so we can help you.

Comment: @equisde: Code Added to the Question body.

Comment: I suppose that code is executed when loading your DataGrid. If so, there is nothing in your code which might cause the above mentioned problem. Make sure you don't have code on `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` or `DataGridView.CellEnter` events

Comment: @equisde: when grid loaded initially the Column with ComboCell remains blank. you can select the item later. But when you select the item and press the tab to leave the combocell the text turns to corresponding value. Like On Selecting "January" when I leave the cell the Combocell displays 1

Comment: see my answer. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

That code just retrieves the month name and month number from the database and fills the ComboCells with them. It makes no sense that it is being executed each time you leave a ComboCell. Try to perform that operation only during `Load` event.

Please note that the code was wrote on the fly and it's not tested.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

[...]

Using Conn = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DateName(M,'1900-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, X.iMonth) + '-01') sMonth, X.iMonth " & _
                                         " FROM (SELECT TOP 12 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) iMonth from sys.objects) X", Conn)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim ComboCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

            DataGridView1("sNotes", dr.Index) = ComboCell
            ComboCell.DataSource = dt
            ComboCell.DisplayMember = "sMonth"
            ComboCell.ValueMember = "iMonth"
        Next

[...]

End Sub
```

For retrieving the month number (`ValueMember`), do not worry about that, it will be internally selected when you choose a month from the displayed month names (`DisplayMember`)

The only thing you need is loop through all ComboCells and retrieve its selected value.

```
    Dim monthValues as Integer()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
         monthValues(i) = dr.Cells("sNotes").SelectedValue;
         i += 1
    Next
```

Comment: Sorry then. I misunderstood your comment on the original post. Then you'll need to find the code which is causing the erroneous behavior. Are you sure you haven't code when a cell is loosing the focus? `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` or `DataGridView.CellEnter` among others are events which might be triggered when you change from a combo cell to another cell

Comment: What is the type of the DataGridView data source for column `iMonth` at database level? Maybe when the code tries to create the `DataTable` to fill up the `DataGridView` comboBox column the `iMonth` type is `Integer`

Comment: Its a auto generated sequence using ROW_NUMBER function. Must be integer. You can see the SQL written in the mentioned code

Comment: I mean the database column data type. If it is `Integer` the datatable column type will be `Integer` and the DataGridView column will be `Integer`, not allowing to the column to contain other data type values. That could be the cause.

Comment: There is no database column involved actually. Query is: SELECT DateName(M,'1900-' + X.iMonth + '-01') sMonth, X.iMonth FROM (SELECT TOP 12 CONVERT(VARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)) iMonth from sys.objects) X

Comment: What?? You're retrieving the result set from `sys.objects` which is a system table. How is it possible that there is not an involved column?? Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384684/cells-show-the-value-member-id-instead-display-member) of a colleague withe the same issue as you.

Comment: Here I am not allowed to post the images. You can visit this link to get the idea of what I am saying. Scroll down to last comment:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5248e4b-1b38-4f54-9280-ce25be0d1b90/datagridview-cell-with-type-as-datagridviewcomboboxcell-not-working-as-expected?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: I already know what you're saying and what is your problem. I did read the question before answering. I bet your problem is related with data types since your combo boxes are being populated from a datatable which is filled up from a table.